# ApplicationRecord: accessing model parent inside scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I'm having some trouble understanding scope and when certain variables are accessible within Rails models. I am trying to access the parent of an EventInstance in order to determine whether it occurs in a certain time range.

```
class EventInstance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event

  # Event starts between 12am and 10am
  scope :morning, -> { where(start_time: (event.start_time.midnight...event.start_time.change(hour: 10)) ) }

  def event_name
    # This works
    event.name
  end

end
```

Excuse my ignorance as I'm not quite up to speed on the magic of Rails. Why can I access `event` inside `event_name`, but not inside the scope? Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes), defining a scope is "exactly the same as defining a class method". You could accomplish the same thing by doing:

```
class EventInstance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event

  # Event starts between 12am and 10am
  def self.morning
    where(start_time: (event.start_time.midnight...event.start_time.change(hour: 10)) )
  end

  def event_name
    # This works
    event.name
  end

end
```

Or even:

```
class EventInstance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event

  class << self 

    # Event starts between 12am and 10am
    def morning
      where(start_time: (event.start_time.midnight...event.start_time.change(hour: 10)) )
    end

  end

  def event_name
    # This works
    event.name
  end

end
```

In all those cases, you can't call the method on an instance of `EventInstance` because, well, it's an instance and not a class.

I imagine you could do something like:

```
class EventInstance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event

  delegate :start_time, to: :event

  # Event starts between 12am and 10am
  def in_morning?
    start_time.in?(start_time.midnight...start_time.change(hour: 10))
  end

  def event_name
    # This works
    event.name
  end

end
```

To determine if an instance of `EventInstance` occurs between 12am and 10am.

I will also note that [Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%c3%b6rg-w-mittag) wishes to say:

> I am one of those Ruby Purists who likes to point out that there is no such thing as a class method in Ruby. I am perfectly fine, though, with using the term *class method* colloquially, **as long as it is fully understood by all parties that it is a colloquial usage**. In other words, if you *know* that there is no such thing as a class method and that the term "class method" is just short for "instance method of the singleton class of an object that is an instance of `Class`", then there is no problem. But otherwise, I have only seen it obstruct understanding.

Let it be fully understood by all parties that the term *class method* is used above in its colloquial sense.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up having to use some raw SQL to do exactly what I needed to do, but your answer helped me figure that out.